# MySQL left join with '-' character in a column

Tags: mysql, join

Here are some data in my filelocation table:

```
Filelocation_table
+-----+-------------+---------------------+
| id  | f_id        | f_location          |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+
|   1 | 1           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   2 | 2           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   3 | 3           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   4 | 4           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   5 | 5           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   6 | 6           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   7 | 7           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   8 | 8           | App. Box March 2017 |
|   9 | 9           | App. Box March 2017 |
|  10 | 10          | App. Box March 2017 |
|  11 | 11          | App. Box March 2017 |

and so on...

| 294 | 79-EC       | EC B1               |
| 295 | 80-EC       | EC B1               |
| 296 | 81-EC       | EC B1               |
| 297 | 82-EC       | EC B1               |
| 298 | 83-EC       | EC B1               |
| 299 | 84-EC       | EC B1               |
| 300 | 85-EC       | EC B1               |
| 301 | 86-EC       | EC B1               |
| 302 | 87-EC       | EC B1               |
| 303 | 1-processed | Active 1            |
| 304 | 2-processed | Active 1            |
| 305 | 3-processed | PR 1                |
| 306 | 4-processed | PR 1                |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+
```

I got a problem in my query below:

```
SELECT  docu_id.id, /* For checking purposes if it match with the f_id */
        filelocation.f_id, /* For checking purposes if it match with the id */
        docutype,
        f_location,
        bpnum,
        lastname,
        firstname,
        middlename,
        ponum,
        claimtype
FROM docu_id

left join filelocation on
        filelocation.f_id = docu_id.id

left join f_dates on 
        filelocation.f_id = f_dates.f_id
```

It gives the following result:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id  | f_id        | docutype    | f_location          | bpnum      | lastname     | firstname      | middlename | ponum | claimtype                       |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|   1 | 1           | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | JULIO          | -          | -     | FUNERAL                         |
|   2 | 2           | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ELEUTERIO      |            |       | COMPULSORY LIFE                 |
|   3 | 3           | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ZORAIDA        |            |       | EMPLOYEES COMPENSATION          |

 /* and so on... */

|  86 | 86-EC       | APPLICATION | EC B1               | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | DANILO         | -          | -     | REQUEST                         |
|  87 | 87-EC       | APPLICATION | EC B1               | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | LIBERATA       | -          | -     |                                 |
|   1 | 1-processed | APPLICATION | Active 1            | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | JULIO          | -          | -     | FUNERAL                         |
|   2 | 2-processed | APPLICATION | Active 1            | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ELEUTERIO      |            |       | COMPULSORY LIFE                 |
|   3 | 3-processed | APPLICATION | PR 1                | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ZORAIDA        |            |       | EMPLOYEES COMPENSATION          |
|   4 | 4-processed | APPLICATION | PR 1                | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | FLORA          |            |       | PRE-NEED                        |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
306 rows in set, 19656 warnings (0.05 sec)
```

The f_id '87-EC' is match with the id '87'

And this query corrected the problem:

```
SELECT  docu_id.id,  /* For checking purposes if it match with the f_id */
        filelocation.f_id, /* For checking purposes if it match with the id */
        docutype,
        f_location,
        bpnum,
        lastname,
        firstname,
        middlename,
        ponum,
        claimtype
FROM docu_id

left join filelocation on
        concat(filelocation.f_id, 'a') = concat(docu_id.id, 'a')

left join f_dates on 
        filelocation.f_id = f_dates.f_id
```

This query returns the expected result:

```
+-----+------+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id  | f_id | docutype    | f_location          | bpnum      | lastname     | firstname      | middlename | ponum | claimtype                       |
+-----+------+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|   1 | 1    | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | JULIO          | -          | -     | FUNERAL                         |
|   2 | 2    | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ELEUTERIO      |            |       | COMPULSORY LIFE                 |
|   3 | 3    | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ZORAIDA        |            |       | EMPLOYEES COMPENSATION          |
|   4 | 4    | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | FLORA          |            |       | PRE-NEED                        |

 and so on...

| 214 | 214  | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ERNESTO        | -          | -     | SEPARATION                      |
| 215 | 215  | APPLICATION | App. Box March 2017 | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx   | ROLANDO        |            |       | SEPARATION                      |
+-----+------+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
215 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Should I not use the '-' character? 
And why MySQL is matching the '87' with '87-EC', 
but do not match when i concat it with 'a' in the end. (87a  /  87-ECa)?

> I replace the numbers and last name with xxxxxxx since i am posting confidential data.

Comment: It's possible that `86-EC` is numerically equivalent and so they're joined, but that seems like MySQL being over-eager. It's generally best to join on two columns with identical types, especially those that are properly indexed.

Comment: You mean, you need only numbers of f_id field?

Comment: I have different tables, each table has its own Type, like the EC, Application, Voucher, and a default table.

Then a table for their locations
for the default table, i just use the id then insert it in f_id (file id)

and for special tables (EC,VOUCHERS, ETC) I insert them with their corresponding id with '-TYPE' (1-APPLICATION, 1-VOUCHER) in f_id

Comment: You could just use `filelocation.f_id = concat(docu_id.id)` because the problem seems to be that the left part of the comparison is converted into a number automatically instead of the right part into a string to match data types.

Comment: @maraca i think it is vice-versa, it is the f_id that is automatically being converted to match the docu_id.id

Thanks you all for the comments and reply.

Comment: @MjdeLima you're right, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now.
I look at the warning from mysql command and it shows the following:

```
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1-EC' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1-EC' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1-EC' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1-EC' |
 /* and so on and on */
```

By converting the id from docu_id table

```
cast(docu_id.id as char(10))
```

Now,all are properly matched i do not need to concat it anymore.

Comment: cast(... as char) and concat(...) will do the same, because concat casts implicitly.

Comment: @maraca thank you :)
Phew, now all my problems are solved.